# Wildcard search that retains wildcard match

Tags: regex, notepad++, wildcard

I'm trying to parse a text file in notepad++ to find any instance of a group ID:

```
id=group00001
```

... with the intention of adding a newline after each.

As group IDs are different each time (but always 5 characters) I gather I need to use regular expression searches for wildcards. But I'm struggling to find a way to do so without wiping out the ID.

For instance, a find and replace as follows:

```
Find: id=group.....
Replace: id=group.....\r\n
```

Finds all of them, but replaces the ID with ".....".

I can't get my head around the more complicated regular expression stuff that would solve my problem - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Find what:(group[\d]{5})
Replace with: \1\r\n
```

What I'm saying is:

Find every word `group` followed by a digit with five characters(`[\d]{5}`) and then replace by all regex group 1 (which is the sentence inside the parenthesis) plus \r\n

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that really helped. So I assume that you can have multiple output groups, if you structure your query to have multiple sets of () brackets?

Comment: Glad that it helped. Yes you are right you can have multiple groups. But Notepad++ imposed a group limit (don't know why and how much, never tested). And parenthesis inside parenteshis is also groups and the counting order change a bit like: (blah(bleh))(blih) group1=(blah(bleh)); group2=(bleh); group3=(blih); and there is a group0 which is all sentence (blah(bleh))(blih)

Comment: Cheers. I wasn't expecting to need to use that any time soon, but I did! Turns out some of the IDs in my file were 6 characters, so I ended up splitting them in half with the newline. I managed to fix it by finding (group[\d]{5})\r\n([\d]{1}) and replacing with \1\2\r\n .

Comment: It could be done with just: `(group[\d]{5,6})\r\n` {5,6} means that it can be 5 to 6 chars :)